# should libaio engine to be used with unbuffered io (direct)only?

Tags: performance-testing

I was trying to get performance numbers (simple 4K random read) using fio tool with ioengine as libaio.
I observe that if direct io is disabled (direct=0), then iops fell drastically. when direct=1 was provided the iops were 50 times better!

```
setup: fio being run from a linux client connected to a PCIe based 
appliance over Fibre Channel.
```

Here is snipped from my fio config file:

```
[global]
filename=/dev/dm-30
size=10G
runtime=300
time_based
group_reporting

[test]
rw=randread
bs=4k
iodepth=16
runtime=300
ioengine=libaio
refill_buffers
ioscheduler=noop
#direct=1
```

With this setup, I observed the iops to be around 8000 and when I enabled direct=1 in this above shown config file, I see that iops jump to 250K! (which is realistic in case of the setup I am using)

So, my question is if we use libaio engine, using buffered i/o has any issues? is it mandatory that if we use libaio, we should stick to direct io?

Comment: Also see https://serverfault.com/questions/918896/ssd-iops-on-linux-direct-much-faster-than-buffered-fio which neatly summarizes the [answer to "Is it valid to set direct=0 when using libaio?"](https://github.com/axboe/fio/issues/512#issuecomment-356604533) which is in the fio bug tracker.

Answer (score 4):

Per [the docs on Kernel Asynchronous I/O (AIO) Support for Linux](http://lse.sourceforge.net/io/aio.html):

> What Does Not Work?
>
> - AIO read and write on files opened without O_DIRECT (i.e. normal buffered filesystem AIO). On ext2, ext3, jfs, xfs and nfs, these do not return an explicit error, but quietly default to synchronous or rather non-AIO behaviour (i.e io_submit waits for I/O to complete in these cases). For most other filesystems, -EINVAL is reported.

In short, if you don't use `O_DIRECT`, AIO still "works" for many of the most common file systems, but becomes a slow form on synchronous I/O (you may as well have just used `read`/`write` and saved yourself a few system calls). The massive performance increase is the result of actually benefiting from asynchronous behavior.

So to answer the question in your title: **Yes, `libaio` should only be used with unbuffered/`O_DIRECT` file descriptors if you expect to derive *any* benefit from it.**